# Regex: Exclude first line with brackets

Tags: php, html

I am trying to strip all HTML brackets, except anything from the first line of code using this REGEX

(?ms)(?!\A)<[^>]*>

It's very close to working, unfortunately it strips the closing brackets  from the first line as well. The example I am working with is:

```
<div id="uniquename">https://www.example.com?item_id=10302</div>
<div id="uniqname2">
<div id="uniqname3">
<h2 id="uniqnametitle">Title</h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-3 columns">Example:</div>
<div class="large-9 columns"><b>Sub example</b></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-3 columns">Additional</div>
```

The current REGEX removes all other HTML tags and excludes the first line with the exception of the trailing div close tag and outputs the following:

```
<div id="uniquename">https://www.example.com?item_id=10302
Title
Example:
Sub example
Additional
```

If there is a better way to perform the REGEX than excluding the first line I am open to suggestions. Skipping the first line seems to be the easiest way, however, I need the end bracket to stay intact.

What am I missing in my REGEX?

Comment: Just don't do it - use a `HTML` parser.

Comment: It is not clear what your desired output is.

Comment: To also include the </div> tag at the end of the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this
`(?ms)((?<firstline>\A[^\n]*)|(<[^>]*>))`
With substitution
`$firstline`

Playground for your example - https://regex101.com/r/ASItOP/3

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this is through a provided UI and it does not allow the ability to use PHP substitutions and only allows REGEX in the search & replace field. I may need to find an alternative method if it is not possible through REGEX only.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an HTML parser in general...

However, you can do:

```
$ cat <(head -n 1 file) <(sed 1d file | sed -E 's/<[^>]*>//g; /^$/d')
```

Or an awk:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1 {print; next}
      {gsub(/<[^>]*>/,""); if ($0) print}' file
```

Either prints:

```
<div id="uniquename">https://www.example.com?item_id=10302</div>
Title
Example:
Sub example
Additional
```

Comment: I should have stated in the original post that this is REGEX for PHP. I was unsuccessful using the examples you provided.

Comment: Do it the same way in general: 1) grab the first line; 2) substitute for the remainder; 3) combine together.

Comment: @dawg : does `sed 1d` achieve the same result as `sed -nE '2,$ p'` ?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 1 : just realized it could be massively simplified

> ```
> gawk 'NR==!_ || (NF=NF)*/./' FS='<[^>]+>' OFS=
> ```

---

> ```
> mawk 'NR==!_ || (NF=NF)*/./' FS='^(<[^>]+>)+|(<[/][^>]+>)+$' OFS=
> ```

```
 1  <div id="uniquename">https://www.example.com?item_id=10302</div>
 2  Title
 3  Example:
 4  Sub example
 5  Additional
```